# How can i run bat file i just added to the resources in my project properties?

Tags: c#, winforms

I went to my project > properties > resources > add existing file > test.bat
Now i have this code :

```
private void Information()
{

}
```

I call this function from a button click event.

I want to execute the bat file, so every user which will use my program will be able to execute the bat file directly from the program.
The bat file just create dxdiag.txt in a specific directory.

How can i do that?

Comment: What you 'have' is an empty method that you want somebody else to fill in for you. That hardly constitutes an attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the batch file into the executable file folder and then use [the Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, yourBatFileName));
```

Pay attention that usually your solution is compiled into the Debug folder or into the Release folder depending on your configuration (so you have to put the file in the correct one).

Comment: He said that the bat file is added as a resource. In this case, he has to load it and execute it from the resources. What is the content of the bat file ? Can't you just use Process class and send some parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this class

[Process.Start Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for parameters...

```
var myProg = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
myProg .StartInfo.FileName = "file name with full path";   
myProg .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProg .StartInfo.Arguments = "";
myProg .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProg .StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProg .Start();
myProg .StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Dump();
```